# MariaDB ColumnStore server doesn't accept connections after 10 minutes

Tags: mariadb

I have a MariaDB ColumnStore server running on a docker container. Docker runs on an Azure VM. I configured all the permissions and I can connect to the server from remote machines and run queries. Also, I can connect from my Tomcat application running on a Kubernetes node on Azure.

This is the problem: after 10 minutes, the connection is lost, and I cannot reconnect again from neither the SQL client nor the application server. I get the error:

> Could not connect to HostAddress{host='X.X.X.X', port=3308,
> type='master'}. Host 'Y.Y.Y.Y' is not allowed to connect to this
> MariaDB server

Where X.X.X.X is the MariaDB server, and Y.Y.Y.Y is the client. Again, this works fine right after the server starts.

I upgraded the JAR driver to the latest version 3.1.3 but the problem persists.

How to tackle this problem? I'm ruling out any type of permissions or network configurations, as this works fine the first few minutes.

**UPDATE**
I'm running the same docker container on Windows without any problems and without changing any configurations

Comment: What is the value of `max_connections`?  How many connections is Tomcat configured for?  Have you reached that limit?

Comment: What does the container stdout/error log say?

Comment: @RickJames there's no max_connections defined, what's the default?

Comment: @danblack there are no errors in the log

Comment: @RickJames Tomcat doesn't have any max_connections defined, however I don't think Tomcat is the problem because I cannot connect from my SQL client either

Comment: @ps0604 - In mysql, do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';`  I don't know the setting in tomcat.

Comment: @RickJames this shows 210, so that's more than enough

Comment: @ps0604 - But if Tomcat asks for 210 or more, there can be problems -- such as what you are experiencing.

Comment: @RickJames These are the Tomcat/Tomee parameters that can be configured in the data access, please take a look at the `Supported Properties` section and tell me what I can change to solve the problem. Thanks. https://tomee.apache.org/datasource-config.html

Comment: @ps0604 - I'm confused; I thought Tomcat and Apache were totally separate products.

Comment: And for Apache, here are some tips:  https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/increase-max-connections-apache/  (cf "threads", "workers", "child", "servers" "connectionsperchild".)  I get lost whenever try to change Apache.